# Satz mit den meisten aufeinanderfolgenden Verben

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, curiosity

Es geht um Sätze mit aufeinanderfolgenden Verben ohne andere Wortarten oder Satzzeichen dazwischen.

Beispiele (Länge der längsten Verbfolge in Klammern):

> Ich schreibe einen Brief (1)
>
> Ich habe einen Brief schreiben müssen (2)
>
> Der Brief muss geschrieben werden (3)
>
> Der Brief hätte geschrieben werden müssen (4)

Ein Bekannter meinte, dass es nicht möglich sei, einen korrekten Satz mit mehr als vier aufeinanderfolgenden Verben zu formulieren, aber nach einiger Zeit ist mir ein Satz mit fünf eingefallen:

> Er war nicht so blöd, wie man hätte geneigt sein können anzunehmen.

Ist das auch mit mehr als fünf Verben möglich?

Ich habe jetzt eine Weile darüber nachgedacht, aber mir ist kein anderer Satz mit fünf oder mehr aufeinanderfolgenden Verben eingefallen.

Comment: Braucht der letzte Satz kein Komma? (Somit fällt das 5. Verb aus.) Somit auch bei der akzeptierten Antwort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man kann deinen Beispielsatz einfach erweitern:

> Er war nicht so blöd, wie man hätte geneigt gewesen sein können anzunehmen.

Comment: Das wäre passender als ein Comment

Comment: @sermonionx Warum? Es scheint meiner Meinung nach die einzige Antwort zu sein, die im Sinne des Fragestellers liegt, da sie keine "loop holes" ausnutzt. Explizit steht die Frage "Ist das auch mit mehr als 5 Verben möglich?" sogar nach seinem Beispielsatz. Direkter lässt sich die Frage kaum beantworten.

Comment: @infinitezero: Das ist eine harte Nuss in Sachen Kommasetzung!

Comment: @infinitezero Letztendlich will man hier einen allgemeinen neuen Einsicht gewinnen, und nur auf diesen gewissen Beispielsatz (m.E.) klein­lich einzugehen hilft wohl nicht viel weiter, wenn man dieses Thema in der Sprache im weiten Blick betrachten will.

Answer (score 4):

Man kann im Grunde alle verfügbaren Modalverben aneinanderreihen, auch wenn pro hinzugefügten Modalverb es immer aufwendiger wird, einen Sitz im Leben für einen solchen Satz zu finden. Aber unmöglich ist es nicht.

> Ich hätte das Honigglas nicht auslecken dürfen.
> Ich hätte das Honigglas nicht auslecken wollen sollen.
> [...]
> Ich hätte das Honigglas nicht auslecken wollen sollen können dürfen müssen mögen.

Nun kann man aber auch die Modalverben mehrfach einsetzen:

> Ich  hätte das Honigglas nicht auslecken dürfen dürfen.

Sprich: Es wäre besser gewesen, Autoritätsperson 1 hätte es Autoritätsperson 2 nicht gestattet, mir zu gestatten, das Honigglas auszulecken.

Comment: Interessant, dass das funktioniert. Es hört sich so falsch an.

Comment: Klar kann man mit Modalverben die Sache unendlich ausdehnen. Aber die Kernfrage war doch eigentlich nach echten Verbschlangen. (Ihre Kritik an meiner Antwort lässt sich genauso gut auf Ihre Antwort anwenden. Schließlich haben die Modalverben alle die gleiche Verbform.)

Answer (score 4):

Ohne Partizipien (also nur finite und infinite Verbformen) können Konstruktionen mit Verben der Wahrnehmung (zB sehen, hören) manchmal viele aufeinanderfolgenden Infinitivformen enthalten.

Ein Zitat aus "Der Prozess" von Franz Kafka:

> Als ich mich ein Weilchen wieder so ruhig verhalten hatte, dass man die Fliegen an der Wand **hätte können gehen hören**, vernahm ich, dass...

Ich bin aber eher der Meinung, dass die Reihenfolge in diesem Fall eher unidiomatisch ist. **Hätte gehen hören können** fände ich besser. Man kann sich auch locker eine realistische Situation vorstellen, wo noch ein Modalverb dazu kommt, ohne dass es zu schräg klingt, und noch verständlich wäre, bspw.:

> Es war im Raum so leise, dass man ihn eigentlich **hätte atmen hören können sollen**.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Downvotes nicht. Ansonsten: Es ist eine philosophische Frage, ob *können* (bzw. *sollen*) hier als Infinitiv oder Partizip Perfekt gewertet werden soll.

Comment: Ach krass, mir ist das erstaunlicherweise echt gar nicht aufgefallen. Ich bin auch der Meinung, dass es sich um serialisierte Verben handelt, was am Beispiel "ist.... worden" klar zu sehen ist, dass diese "ge"-losen Formen keine Infinitive sind. Auch zB nach demselben Muster "Ich habe das da stehen lassen", "...dich kommen sehen", etc.

Answer (score -1):

11. Der Hund der kacken laufen gelassen werden hätte können, hätte spazieren geführt werden müssen.

Comment: Dafür hast du dich angemeldet? :)

Answer (score -3):

Man kann noch Verben im [Partizip](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partizip) einfügen:

> … wie man *nachdenkend* *bestätigt* hätte geneigt sein können *beschwichtigend* anzunehmen.

Ob ein solcher Satz dann noch inhaltlich sinnvoll ist, ist eine andere Frage.

Comment: Das finde ich eine faule Lösung. Klar kann man mit den Partizipien die Sache unendlich ausdehnen. Aber die Kernfrage war doch eigentlich nach echten Verbschlangen...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, aber Prtizipien sind doch auch Verbformen, was unterscheidet sie von anderen Verbformen, damit sie als faul gelten?

Comment: In dem Wikipedia Artikel steht ja auch, dass Partizipien lange nicht als Verben galten. Vielleicht deshalb.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich verstehe die Frage eher so, aus wie vielen Verbformen ein mehrteiliges Prädikat bestehen kann; nicht wie viele von Verben abgeleitete Formen in einem Satz stehen können.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus, das sieht der Fragesteller selbst offenbar anders, sonst hätte er die Antwort nicht akzeptiert. Zudem haben schon im Ausgangssatz drei Verben dieselbe Form (Infinitiv). Außerdem müsste Ihr Kommentar, wenn schon, dann auch unter Christian Geiselmanns Antwort stehen; auch die Modalverben haben dort alle die gleiche Verbform (Infinitiv).

Comment: Nach meinem Verständnis kann ein mehrteiliges Prädikat durchaus aus mehreren Infinitiven bestehen, wobei hierzu andere sicherlich mehr sagen könnten. Das Problem mit Partizipien scheint mir jedenfalls, dass die Frage den maximal möglichen Verbformen galt, während Partizipien mindestens zum gleichen Teil den Adjektiven zuzurechnen wären. Dass in einem Satz beliebig viele Adjektive vorkommen können ist wiederum trivial und könnte geradezu als Umgehung des ursprünglichen Problems aufgefasst werden.

Comment: Ich hab langsam keine Lust mehr. Es wurde nach mehreren Verben gefragt (ohne irgendwelche Einschränkungen), meine Antwort hat mehrere Verben, der Fragesteller war zufrieden(!) und trotzdem wird die Antwort abgewertet und sich als vermeintliche Begründung irgendwas aus den Fingern gesaugt.

Comment: Das Partizip Präsens ist eigentlich keine verbale Form. Es taucht zumindest nicht dort auf, wo die anderen infiniten Verbformen auftauchen – im [Verbalkomplex](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1522) – sondern im [Mittelfeld](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/465).